# Rcpp::export - exporting only the C++ interface, not the R functions

Tags: rcpp, roxygen2

I do not need roxygen2 and Rcpp to create for me the R functions (or maybe I do?) for the exported C++ functions - is there any way to tell `Rcpp::export` *not* to create them? I would be perfectly happy with just `.Call`-ing them directly.

I went through [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.pdf), and [Rcpp Attributes](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) and [Writing a package that uses Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-package.pdf) vignettes, documentation of roxygen2 and multiple threads on SO (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869956/error-when-building-r-package-using-roxygen2)) but I did not find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then it is as simple "well if you don't want a stub function created, do no put an `[[Rcpp::export]]` tag there".

You also confuse what [roxygen2](https://cran.r-project.org/package=roxygen2) does for documentation with what the `compileAttributes()` function does for exporting.

To be plain, only the latter has anything to do with creating interfaces between R and C++. And on the margin, you *do* want them for the free exception handling and RNG setting they give you.  But hey, if you'd rather do without, you can, and that *is* documented.

Comment: Thanks, but I always thought that I need to `[[Rcpp::export]]` so Rcpp does the proper translations of R objects into C++ ones..? Can I directly call something like `NumericVector foo(NumericVectorr x) { return x+1; } ` using `.Call` without exporting it ?

Comment: You appear to be confusing several issues. The translation is done by the C++ code in the package, not by transformations done by `compileAttributes()` when tickled by `[[Rcpp::export]]`.   Rcpp Attributes mostly just adds a lot of (rather helpful !!) glue code, extending what package [inline](https://cran.r-project.org/package=inline)  did before.  You are not forced to use any of these, but I suspect the advantages these offer will compel you to use them--as they do for other people.  Maybe you can claridy your question.

Comment: And/or just _look_ at some other packages. There are well over 900 on CRAN now, just poke around.  Many have internal helper functions in C++ without export tags.

Comment: Thanks. I will stick to standard Rcpp, I was just curious if I can resign from the R functions I didn't need.